# Sqlite get database methods slow

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-sqlite

Ok so i've been banging my head against the wall for couple of days now and i finally came to conclusion.

I am trying to insert one record only when i need to, my response time was pretty slow, around 120ms per record. I've seen most of the threads here on SO about optimising insert statements and i implemented most of the recommended practices; using transaction, using prepared statements etc.

Logging and testing showed me that most of the delay is coming from the basic step "databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase()" it takes around 90ms to get writable database.

Is there any acceptable solution for this problem?

This is my method for inserting:

```
 public static void insertEBlago3(Context context, EItemInvoiceDto itemDto, EParamDto eparamDto) throws Exception {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase database = null;
        try {
            Log.v("Dodaj", "get writable database " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
            database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            // Begin transaction.
            Log.v("Dodaj", "begin transaction " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
            database.beginTransaction();
            Log.v("Dodaj", "Preparing sql " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
            String sqlInsertEBlago3 = "INSERT INTO emaloprod3 (leto, gd, strmst, zaporedna, datdok, casdok, idlokacije, blago, kolicina, "
                    + "osnova, cena, ddv, popust, ncena, rabat, marza, narocilo, naroc, naroc_kol, opomba) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            Log.v("Dodaj", "Before compile " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
            SQLiteStatement stat = database.compileStatement(sqlInsertEBlago3);
            Log.v("Dodaj", "After compile " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
           /***binding data****/
            // End transaction.
            stat.executeInsert();
            Log.v("Dodaj", "Insert " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
            database.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
//          Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
//          e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // End transaction.
            database.endTransaction();
            DBHelper.closeAllConnections(null, null, database);
            Log.v("Dodaj", "Finish " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
        }
    }
```

And this is my log:

```
10-21 10:12:27.278 3759-3759/? V/Dodaj: get writable database 0
10-21 10:12:27.370 3759-3759/? V/Dodaj: begin transaction 92
10-21 10:12:27.370 3759-3759/? V/Dodaj: Preparing sql 92
10-21 10:12:27.370 3759-3759/? V/Dodaj: Before compile 92
10-21 10:12:27.370 3759-3759/? V/Dodaj: After compile 92
10-21 10:12:27.384 3759-3759/? V/Dodaj: Insert 106
10-21 10:12:27.399 3759-3759/? V/Dodaj: Finish 121
```

As you can see getting writable database takes 92 ms

Comment: very weak benchmark ... you need to understand that all thos optimalization that you are reading about is for **multiple** rows inserting ...

Comment: I know, tho i am trying basically everything to get things faster..

Comment: then look at @WangJie 's answer ...

Comment: 120ms is not so big deal(on real device ? or emulator?) ... you should take an account that this operations may use lots of storage IO ... remeberer: *Premature optimization is the root of all evil*

Comment: I am working on a POS system, 120ms for inserting one item on the receipt is pretty slow.

Comment: slow? how much time takes to select the blago? type the kolicina ? and many, many other stuff?

Comment: Around 90ms from start to end. Same problem with getting readable database. Working on that now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can keep only one `SQLiteDatabase` instance in your whole application.

And close it when exit the application.

And you can also use `ORM`(eg. [RapidORM](https://github.com/wangjiegulu/RapidORM), [GreenDao](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO), [ORMLite](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-android)).

Comment: @Selvin I mean that you can cache your `SQLiteDatabase` instance, and it will save your time because `databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase()` is executed only once.

Comment: first I'm not gregaj, second i agree with you about this part (also not only *getWritableDatabase() is executed only once.* there will be no multiple calls to helper's constructor, helper's onCreate...) , but the part about ORMs is not connected with any part of the question ... especially does not apply when you wana speed something up

Comment: Won't that cause lock table problems? I am using more than one method to work with database. I changed my code so databasehelper class is opened only once through getInstance method and i gained like 1ms.

Comment: no, if the methods which are using this instance are synchronized ... or no, if all those methods are called from the same thread ...

Comment: @Selvin Ok, I also agree with that ORM is could not speed up. I recommend that because that ORM cache `SQLiteDatabase` instance.

Comment: @WangJie saved the day! I used one instance of SQliteDatabase and now i am down to 15ms. Thank you!